# How to create 1D array from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My data look like:

```
eval1.head()
0   112
1   98
2   69
3   82
4   91
```

I wanna create 1D array from that.
I've tried:

```
y_test = eval1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True).values
y_test.shape
```

which raises:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

```
y_test = eval1.values
```

returns shape

> (100, 1)

Comment: Since you're setting `inplace=True`, the operation is performed *in-place*, and hence it returns `None`

Comment: A dataframe is 2d, a Series or column of a frame is 1d.